# My Parsing method return null (oci_parse() method)

Tags: php, oracle, plsql

I want to create a class that uses some OCI methods to connect to ORACLE databases.

But my Parse() method is null when I call it and my FetchArray() method returns nothing

Database php class :

```php
class Database
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private string $login;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private string $password;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private string $description;
    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $connection;
    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $stmt;

    public function __construct(string $login, string $password, string $description)
    {
        $this->login = $login;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->description = $description;
    }


    public function Connection($character_set = null, $session_mode = null)
    {
        $this->connection = oci_connect($this->login, $this->password, $this->description, $character_set,    $session_mode);
    }

   
    public function Parse(string $sql)
    {
        $this->stmt = oci_parse($this->connection, $sql);
    }


    public function Execute()
    {
        oci_execute($this->stmt);
    }
```

Test Page.php :

```php
$database = new Database($login, $pass, $descr);
        $database->Connection();
        if ($database->IsConnected()) {
            $database->Parse($sql);
            $database->Execute();
            while ($row = $database->FetchArray(OCI_BOTH) != false) {
                // Use the uppercase column names for the associative array indices
                echo $row[0] . " and " . $row['EMAIL']   . " are the same<br>\n";
                echo $row[1] . " and " . $row['NAME'] . " are the same<br>\n";
            }
            $database->Disconnection();
        } else {
            echo 'Error';
        }
```

Currently, the connection to the database is successful.

FetchArray method :

```php
public function FetchArray($mode = null)
    {
        oci_fetch_array($this->stmt, $mode);
    }
```

Comment: Test and return result of oci_parse - if $this->stmt is false, than statement is not prepared. Depending on SQL syntax, SQL statements should not end with a semi-colon (";"). PL/SQL statements should end with a semi-colon (";"). https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-parse.php

Comment: My request does not end with a semicolon, Parse method return bool type


public function Parse(string $sql): bool
    {
        $this->stmt = oci_parse($this->connection, $sql);
        if ($this->stmt) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a problem. In your while condition, you probaby missed couple brackets, to make it comparing result of fetch to row data to boolean false.

```
$database = new Database($login, $pass, $descr);
        $database->Connection();
        if ($database->IsConnected()) {
            $database->Parse($sql);
            $database->Execute();
            while (($row = $database->FetchArray(OCI_BOTH)) != false) {
                // Use the uppercase column names for the associative array indices
                echo $row[0] . " and " . $row['EMAIL']   . " are the same<br>\n";
                echo $row[1] . " and " . $row['NAME'] . " are the same<br>\n";
            }
            $database->Disconnection();
        } else {
            echo 'Error';
        }
```

This line is updated:

```
        while (($row = $database->FetchArray(OCI_BOTH)) != false) {
```

I think it would be also safe to remove type casting from fetch function

```
public function FetchArray($mode = null):
```

Comment: Yes thanks you, the code works,I removed all return types from my methods and forgot to specify return on some methods.
Finally, I had forgotten a parenthesis on the while